# NodeJS Firebase Circular Buffer or Queue

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, circular-buffer

I am using Firebase with Nodejs. I want to limit number of records in`battleReports` by number N. But not just limit. If new data will come and there is already N records in `battleReports`, delete oldest one and add new one. I want to implement something like circular queue or buffer. Is it possible?

```
  players: {
    'player1-id': {
      battleReports: {
        'battle-report-1': {/* report object */},
        'battle-report-2': {/* report object */},
        'battle-report-3': {/* report object */}
        // ... 
      }
    },
    'player2-id': {
      battleReports: {
        'battle-report-1': {/* report object */},
        'battle-report-2': {/* report object */},
        'battle-report-3': {/* report object */}
        // ... 
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but I would suggest changing the children of `battleReports` to use auto-generated key (e.g. the `push` method).

That way the `battleReports` will always be sorted in order by when they were added.

Regardless, create the database function that looks something like this:

```
this.battleReportLimiter = functions.database.ref('battleReports/{newReport}').onCreate(event => {
  return admin.database().ref('battleReports').orderByKey().limitToFirst(1).once('value').then(event => {
    return admin.database().ref('battleReports').child(event).remove();
  });
});
```

You don't have to use auto-generated keys and `orderByKey()`, you can also use the other rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) if you want (that requires an `indexOn: [<child>]` rule in your database rules).

**Summary:** the solution is just to create some sort of ordering technique either by key or by child/value. Then you just need to listen for onCreate using a variable like `{newReport}` or listen for `childAdded` on `battleReports`. Then use any technique to get the oldest (always the first key when auto-generated) and then delete it.